# Sending data from Javascript to Servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets, get

I want to make an ajax get call to  server.Till now I always used:

```
$.get("/FruitResults?fruit="+fruitname+"&color="+colorname,function(data){addToTables(data);},"text");
```

for sending parameters fruit,color.Now if I have many fruits,their color,price..

```
{apple:{color:red,price:30},orange:{color:orange,price:10}}
```

and such a big list of fruits, how shoud i send this to servlet using Ajax call., in what format? and at servlet side also, how should I retrieve the request parameters from the request object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Http `get` method is not suitable for sending complex data. Therefore, you must use `post` method to send a complex data from client to the server. And you can use JSON format to encode this data. Example code is as follows:

```
var fruits = {apple:{color:red,price:30},orange:{color:orange,price:10}};
$.post("/FruitResults", JSON.stringify(fruits), function(response) {
    // handle response from your servlet.
});
```

Note that, since you used the `post` method, you have to handle this request in `doPost` method of the servlet instead of `doGet`. To retrieve the posted data you must read the input stream of the servlet request as follows:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {

  String jsonString = new String(); // this is your data sent from client
  try {
    String line = "";
    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
      jsonString += line;
  } catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  // you can handle jsonString by parsing it to a Java object. 
  // For this purpose, you can use one of the Json-Java parsers like gson**.
}
```

** Link for **gson**: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/