# Json based webservice in java and client in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, web-services

I am new in web service development. Currently I am developing an application (in html5 using javascript and jquery) in which I wanted to send data to web service in Json format.

My question are:  1) How to send(post) data to web service using javascript ?  2) How to retrieve json data at server side ?  3) How to get data from the web service in json format ?  4) How to retrieve json data at client side ?

Comment: Have you not looked at any tutorials on Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Cast you json to string than send to server. In the server side cast it json again.

Comment: can you please give me an exmple or its link ?

Comment: @Raaga can you use php?

Comment: no php only java at web service side and html5, javascript, jquery at client side.

Comment: @Raaga If I don't misunderstand you use java servlet. Then this link will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424313/sending-data-from-javascript-to-servlet

Answer (score 0):

JSON is just a way to encapsulate data. 
You should have parses on both sides that parse the json into data you can work with. On your Java serve you can use e.g. https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

Answer (score 0):

1. Easiest would be to use jquery ajax() function.

   $.ajax({
               type: 'post', 
               dataType: 'json', 
               data: { "var1": value1, "var2": value2 },
               url: 'www.example.com' })
           .success( function() {
               console.log( 'success' );
           });
2. This depends on what backend do you use on server, I can reccomend **node.js** with **express**.
3. The same as p1, the only difference that you will have to parse data you have received in success() function.
4. I am not sure if I understand correctly what you mean.